# Browsers ignore justification for runtime generated content

Tags: javascript, css, justify

A common trick to evenly distribute blocks of content within a container is to give them a `display:inline-block` CSS property, and then apply `text-align:justify` to the parent container, so:

```
<section>
  <div></div><!-- repeat X times -->
</section>
```

And CSS:

```
section {
    text-align:justify;
}
div {
    width:200px;
    height:50px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

This works fine in all browsers, including IE8+, [as shown in this sample Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/VNUus/). The last line reverts to left alignment since I didn't set `text-align-last`, which is fine, and unsupported by Webkit stable anyway.

However, if you now start generating additional `div` elements with Javascript, the layout engines somehow seem to completely forget about justification.

[Refer to this second Fiddle which includes a periodical function adding a `div` every second](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/AdLuT/). I have tested this in Chrome beta, Firefox latest, IE10 and IE11 - and all of them first screw up the last line completely, semi-justifying the generated content based on the previously available space, and then just left-aligning all following elements.

I have tried everything in Firebug and IE/Chrome dev tools, changing and resetting properties, but can't trigger a 'rejustification' in any way - they accept `text-align:right`, but if you then reset it to `text-align:justify` it just jumps back to left alignment again. Playing with `white-space`, `letter-spacing` and `word-spacing` just have no visible effect.

The [relevant section in the W3 CSS standards](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#alignment-prop) provides no justification (pun intended) for this behaviour either as far as I can see.

Is there any fix or workaround for this issue?

Comment: The thing with the last line is normal for justified text. Since the last line of a paragraph is likely to be shorter than the rest, it would look strange typographically to try to justify it. The thing with dynamically generated elements is really, really strange though. Even weirder that it happens in all browsers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In essence, it needs a space between each div as is the case for the ones in the HTML.

So do something like (I'm not familiar with mootools so there may be a simpler way)

```
(function(){
    $('root').grab(new Element('div'));
    $('root').grab(new Element('span', {
        'text': ' '
    }));
}).periodical(1000);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/AdLuT/1/  (Perfect in FF and IE, slightly out in Chrome, which suggests a different problem there.)

Comment: Wow, hero - I completely overlooked that indeed. It is indeed a matter of appending a space, with `.appendText(' ')` by the way, see [updated simplified fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/AdLuT/2/). Very curious that Chrome is still a few pixels off indeed though.

Comment: Ah, right, forgot about that. I wonder if there's a way with CSS to treat each element as a "word" without having to add spaces.

Comment: setting `text` to two spaces seems to line up perfectly in Chrome

Comment: @DaggNabbit in a few months you should be able to use flexboxes universally to solve this issue, in combination with [`justify-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content).

Comment: Wth, it works fine indeed with 2 spaces instead of 1 - so still some kind of bug in Chrome methinks.